# Find The correct process Id in visual studio for debugging sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

When i want to attache a process Id with the `w3wp.exe` to my solution in visual studio and debug my web part in sharepoint I have more than one `w3wp.exe` process . How can I find the correct process id of my sitecollection and attach my solution to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Command Prompt and Run following command

"appcmd list wps"

It wil gives you all app pool with id.

(appcmd.exe can be found in %windir%\system32\inetsrv)